# Split string and iterate for each value in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, tokenize

I have a requirement in Oracle where I have to pass a comma separated string of country codes to an Oracle stored procedure.

Inside a stored procedure I want to split the string on comma and iterate for each country code.

I want a SP which is similar as follows:

```
PROCEDURE Get_Query
(
  v_company IN VARCHAR2,

) IS
sqlstr VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
/*
split the v_company on comma (e.g. IN,US,...etc)
iterate for each country code  

*/
END;
```

Comment: This is such a prevalent request (try Googling, "stackoverflow oracle parse csv string").  There is no shortage of documentation on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/dbms_utility-comma_to_table/).

The **DBMS_UTILITY** package provides various utility subprograms. One such useful utility is **COMMA_TO_TABLE** procedure, which converts a comma-delimited list of names into a PL/SQL table of names.

For example,

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  2    l_tablen BINARY_INTEGER;
  3    l_tab DBMS_UTILITY.uncl_array;
  4    CURSOR cur
  5    IS
  6      SELECT 'word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6' val FROM dual;
  7    rec cur%rowtype;
  8  BEGIN
  9    OPEN cur;
 10    LOOP
 11      FETCH cur INTO rec;
 12      EXIT
 13    WHEN cur%notfound;
 14      DBMS_UTILITY.comma_to_table (
 15      list => rec.val, tablen => l_tablen, tab => l_tab);
 16      FOR i IN 1 .. l_tablen
 17      LOOP
 18        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i || ' : ' || trim(l_tab(i)));
 19      END LOOP;
 20    END LOOP;
 21    CLOSE cur;
 22  END;
 23  /
1 : word1
2 : word2
3 : word3
4 : word4
5 : word5
6 : word6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**UPDATE** As @ruudvan points out, there are restrictions for using `COMMA_TO_TABLE` like it won't work if you have **keywords** as delimited string like `IS,AS` etc.

To overcome the restrictions of `COMMA_TO_TABLE`, there are many other ways of doing it, see [**How to split comma delimited string into rows in Oracle**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-using-oracle-sql/)

For example, you could use REGULAR EXPRESSION as shown below:

**Test case**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE Get_Query(
  3      v_company IN VARCHAR2 )
  4  IS
  5  BEGIN
  6    
  7    FOR i IN
  8    (SELECT level,
  9      trim(regexp_substr(v_company, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
 10    FROM dual
 11      CONNECT BY regexp_substr(v_company , '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
 12    )
 13    LOOP
 14      -- do something
 15      dbms_output.put_line('Company code no.'||i.level||' = '||i.str);
 16    END LOOP;
 17  END;
 18  /

Procedure created.

SQL> sho err
No errors.
```

Let's check:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> EXEC get_query('COMP1,COMP2,COMP3,COMP4');
Company code no.1 = COMP1
Company code no.2 = COMP2
Company code no.3 = COMP3
Company code no.4 = COMP4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I think you should rather put the regexp_substr method here instead of comma_to_table. Whenever you recommend someone comma_to_table, I feel like you should also inform them about it's limitations. Tom Kyte sums it up [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1415803954123). It might not give you correct results even in this specific example of country codes because OP can have country codes like "AS" and "IS" which are reserved words and comma_to_table won't be able to process them.

Comment: @ruudvan Of course there are restricts with the built-in package. That's the reason I have provided the link to my article where I have demonstrated various methods. I will leave it up to OP to come back and ask if he needs more assistance. If I have to go deeper into details and provide every micro-details here, then it would be like writing a book. Anyway, thanks for the comment. I will be more than happy to help OP if he comes back with further concerns.

Comment: You have sufficient rep to know how StackOverflow works.  We're supposed to provide working answers *on this site*.  Offering a sub-par solution- and as @ruudvan points out, `COMMA_TO_TABLE()` is just that - plus a link to your blog just isn't good enough.

Comment: @APC and ruudvan, fair enough guys. Added a complete working solution. Thanks for pushing me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This use of regular expressions converts the input string into a stream of tokens which can be processed like the result set of any other SELECT statement.

```
PROCEDURE Get_Query
(
  v_company IN VARCHAR2,

) IS
    sqlstr VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN

    for rec in (select distinct regexp_substr(v_company, '[^,]+', 1, level) as ctry
    from dual
    connect by level <= regexp_count (v_company, '[,]')  +1
   loop
        do_something ( rec.ctry );

    end loop;
END;
```